# When using https, wordpress doesn't use https for CSS and JS, and admin doesn't work. How do I fix this?

Tags: css, wp-admin, ssl

So I recently, built and LAMP server and installed wordpress on it. I connected it to the web via a reverse ssh tunnel using serveo.net. I decided to add ssl and the rest of the website seem to work fine, but wordpress keeps breaking when I try to use ssl. I went to the general settings and changed the urls to http instead of https, but when I load the pages, in the source code the css and js urls are using http instead of https, so they won't load. Then wp-admin part won't even load. How do I fix this? I've looked at quite a few posts about people having similar problems, but none of them helped.

Comment: I am very much new to wordpress development. I was about to add ssl ceritificate and for that went to General settings and add the https and removed http and saved it. After that i am not even able to login into wordpress admin. Please help me out ASAP

Comment: @ashutoshbatta If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/220720)

Answer (score 1):

Check two things:

- in the wp-options table, the site URLs (in two places) should be the full URL, as in https://www.example.com .
- check the site's htaccess file for proper rewrite of http to https.

For a htaccess rule, this one works in most case:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Then look at your theme files to ensure that any references to CSS/JS include the https protocol, not http. Most well-written themes will use relative rather than absolute references to files to include.

It's also possible a plugin might be specifying http rather than https.

Use the Network tab in Developer Tools (usually F12 in your browser) to look at each request to see where it is coming from. If the request is to a plugin folder, then check the code in there.

Comment: I'm using the default theme. twentynieteen,I'm using the default theme. twentynieteen. The database entries are correct, but the head section has stuff like <link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='http://jtjumper.serveo.net/wp/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.0.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-theme-css'  href='http://jtjumper.serveo.net/wp/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/theme.min.css?ver=5.0.3' type='text/css' media='all' />

Comment: If I look at the page source on my test (hosted) site with the 2019 theme, the href for those statements includes the https: protocol. And I have the htaccess shown in my answer. And my wp-options table contains https://www.example.com , not just www.example.com . Perhaps yours is not set up that way?

Comment: There's not enough space in the comments for the source but this is the link for the page https://jtjumper.serveo.net/wp/
my wp-options table has both, which are both https

Comment: Do you have some caching plugin? Is your htaccess rewriting http to https?

Comment: the only plugins I have are akismet, loginizer, realy simple ssl, and wordfence

Comment: Disable all your plugins (especially really simple ssl). Then set your htaccess as shown. Then run a search/replace plugin (I like "Better Search and Replace") and search for http://www.yourdomain.com and replace it with https://www.yourdomain.com .

Comment: The search-replace string mentioned in the comment above should say: search for `http://yourdomain.com` and replace it with `https://yourdomain.com` - because of formatting, it id not show correctly in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Had the similar issue.

This [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/75921/173852) solves most of the issues and I'm hoping you've gone through it.

The reason, I found, for HTTPS (SSL) not working on my Wordpress even after changing
1. Virtual Host File aka `<web_directory>.conf` file inside `/ect/apache2/sites-available`
2. `wp-config` file inside `/var/www/<web_directory>/`
3. [For AWS EC2 Users] Adding a load balancer with a SSL certificate for HTTPS connections

If after doing all this, you can view your website w/o CSS and JS working, then,

Last step

1. Inside your Wordpress Dashboard, go to `Settings>General`

   Under, `Wordpress Address (URL)` add, `https://<yourdomain>.com`
   Under, `Site Address (URL)` add, `https://<yourdomain>.com`

I found that, when only `Site Address (URL)` has been activated with the website URL, Wordpress Themes automatically direct towards, the css files with HTTPS aka, `https://<WordPressAddress>/css/index.css`.

Only your domain has SSL access hence, adding your domain name at `Wordpress Address (URL)` solved the problems for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to `wp-config.php` in your `wordpress` root folder.
Also, in `General Settings` on the Admin Panel, change `http` to `https` for your siteurl an home.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Comment: Why? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I hosted my site on Azure webapp service Linux.

Try this plugin. take care when it active it works.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jsm-force-ssl/

> This plugin uses native WordPress filters, instead of PHP’s output
>   buffer, for maximum reliability, performance and caching compatibility
>   (this plugin does not affect caching performance), along with 301
>   permanent redirects for best SEO (301 redirects are considered best
>   for SEO when moving from HTTP to HTTPS).
>
> Honors proxy / load-balancing variables for large hosting
>   environments:
>
> HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL Requirements:
>
> Your web server must be configured with an SSL certificate and able to
>   handle HTTPS request.
>
> Simply activate the plugin and you’re done:
>
> There are no plugin settings to adjust, and no changes are made to
>   your WordPress configuration — simply activate or deactivate the
>   plugin to enable / disable the filters and dynamic redirects.