# On a Https site, Css and Js Url are back to http after redirect the site

Tags: themes, css, url-rewriting, migration

I have a website:
https://media.example.com/blog/

And I want to change into:
https://www.example.com/blog/

I made this transformation in the Wp-DB on the table wp_options, i modified the fields: siteUrl and Home...

Now, after restarting Apache server, I cannot load the Theme Css and Js.
also, while before I was loading all the Css and Js under  href='https, now they are loaded under  href='http.

I read different blog/solutions...
https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/
[SSL Breaks Wordpress CSS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75921/ssl-breaks-wordpress-css)
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/css-broken-after-moving-to-test-subdomain-without-ssl/

but I'm little confused becasue it looks that there is not a unique common solution.

Comment: When you change a site's URL you really need to use a database migration plugin. WP serializes URLs in a lot of different tables, so CSS and JS not loading are a symptom of a larger problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a "Search and Replace" plugin (I like "Better Search and Replace") to search for all http://www.example.com and replace with https://www.example.com . That will fix media URLs, for instance, and other settings.

It could also be that your theme is calling `http` resources rather than `https`. You could look in the Developer screen (F12 in your browser usually) at the Network tab to see what `http` (vs `https`) resources are being loaded, and use that info to find the source code that is using `http` instead of `https`.

Backup your database first, of course, although I've had no problems with the "Better Search and Replace" plugin.

Comment: I don't know if it will work. I got my site on one server and I have to redirect everything on another server/domain...

Comment: You can use htaccess directives to take care of http to https, and redirect to another domain that runs on another server. You'll still need to do a search/replace in the database, but once that is done (with an htaccess that rewrites to https), all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I found this plug in
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/

My site is also behind a load balance and this plugin solved everything.
It's running in real-time (I don't like that), but it keeps everything under control

Comment: All that plugin does is a bunch of add-filters and add-actions to change requests from http to https. Which is what a search/replace plugin will do for any URL in the database. Add a simple http-to-https htaccess directives to rewrite requests to https and you don't need the plugin's overhead.